# Extra spacing below image, How can i remove it?

Tags: html, css

I've got a `div` to show an image and I want the `div` to wrap around the image without putting the actual size in the CSS so I can make the image size bigger/smaller and the `div` just wraps around whatever.

Here is my CSS:

```
.boxart {
    padding:1px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border: solid 1px #cacaca;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.overImage {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff1ce;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 60px;
    border: 1px dashed #111111;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="boxart">
  <div class="overImage">Upload Boxart</div><img width="220" height="200" src="img-url" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two different ways to remove the space below the `img`:

- Change the `vertical-align` property of the `img` to something like `top`:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9n17cjoa/)

  ```
  .boxart > img {
      vertical-align: top;
  }
  ```
- Alternatively, you could change the `display` of the `img` to `block`.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w26mn6q4/)

  ```
  .boxart > img {
      display: block;
  }
  ```

**The reason why both of these approach work:**

An `img` element is `inline` by default.

There is reserved whitespace for `inline` elements for [letters such as f, j, p and q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278) that extend beyond the height of other letters (i.e., letters that hang lower / stand taller..). By changing the `vertical-align` property to something *other* than the default value of `baseline`, the whitespace is removed. By changing the `display` of the element to `block`, the `vertical-align` property no longer has an effect on the element as it is no longer `inline`.

Comment: Thanks, any preference to which to use or is there no advantage / disadvantage to either?

Comment: @Exoon In this case, it really doesn't matter since both solutions work. But i'd probably go with `vertical-align: top` because you maintain the inline behavior of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use display as **inline-flex** for .boxart

Inline-flex helps their child tags to fit the parent tag space either by shrinking or growing.